# How do I emulate protected methods, in Dart?

Tags: dart

(overheard at the office, and we thought others will benefit)

Suppose I have a base class in a library, which provides some basic features, but which is intended to be derived from by the library user.

For example, I have an abstract Greeting class. Subclasses represent specific types of greetings, like HighFiveGreeting or HugGreeting or whatever. Greeting provides some utility functions for subclasses, like `sendGreeting()`. I don't want users of these classes to call `sendGreeting()`.

Is that possible? Is there a better idiom in Dart for this kind of thing?

```dart
library greeting;

abstract class Greeting {
   void sendGreeting(GreetingEvent event) { ... }
}
```

---

```dart
library custom_greeting;
import 'greeting.dart';

class HugGreeting extends Greeting {
   // code here uses sendGreeting()
}
```

---

```dart
library main;
import 'custom_greeting.dart';

var hug = new HugGreeting();
hug.sendGreeting(...); // should not compile
```

---

Comment: And did anyone in your office propose a solution? As far as I know there isn't.

Comment: It would be a greate feature for Dart. Is there an issue opened? http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list

Comment: http://dartbug.com/3193, http://dartbug.com/6119

Comment: There's no "official" answer, but lots of good discussions.

Answer (score 59):

Like stated [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3193#issuecomment-189379596), now there is the `@protected` annotation in the [meta package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta)

I would love to know the reasons why to omit the public|private|protected keywords from the language BTW... :'(

Comment: The public|private keywords are omitted because all members are public unless they begin with an underscore, in which case they are private, which I happen to like. I agree with you about wanting a protected keyword rather than annotation though.

Comment: @MichaelP. yeah but that just stating the fact :-D The question is why they omitted access modifiers and built the underscore mechanism.

Comment: @MichaelP. Bad design: I came here to know if `@protected` works on `_method` or only on `method`. This doubt wouldn't exist if they just gave us `private`, `public` and `protected`. BTW, other languages, like C#, for instance, considers not using an access modifier as public.

Comment: There's a good reason to use naming conventions to denote private/public. What happens if you try to call a private method on a `dynamic`? The language only knows the type of a `dynamic` at run time, so calling a private method has to be a runtime error. The way they have it set up, `foo._bar` is always a syntax error. It's a way of static access checking, and it's a feature with pros and cons, not a defect.

Comment: They could have just introduced a new prefix that indicates the protected modifier instead of introducing the `@protected` attribute.

Comment: Read https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33383 for a long discussion on to have or not to have access modifiers in dart :) Personally, I am still getting used to underscores. I feel that it makes the code a little harder to read, given the Java background.

Answer (score 10):

I believe there's no way to do this, but FWIW, this seems like a situation where composition would be preferable to inheritance:

```dart
class GreetingSender {
    void sendGreeting(GreetingEvent);
}

class HugGreeting {
    GreetingSender _sender;
    HugGreeting(this._sender);

    void hug() {
        // use _sender.sendGreeting()
    }
}
```

Every design which involves calling a protected method implemented in a superclass has a corresponding design where the superclass is replaced by an interface injected through the constructor, and I've yet to encounter a scenario where that doesn't improve things.

Comment: (I've met very few application-code scenarios in which implementation polymorphism - e.g. subtyping for LSP - improved things ;-)

Comment: It seems to me that requiring predictable constructor arguments is frustrating. I think, perhaps, you can use `GreetingSender _sender = GreetingSender();` and forgo the need for declaring a constructor. Still, having a protected member as a part of the superclass is pretty convenient sometimes, like when there are many variables you'd like to make sure are included (otherwise you have a lot of biolerplate code to do whenever you create a new class that includes all of the members of a class format).

Comment: So what exactly has been improved in your example? And how are you going to implement polymorphism without inheritance and protected methods?

Comment: "composition preferable to inheritance" - people who make such statements do not understand the purpose of any.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but someone suggested the following solution, which works for me. I will demonstrate with a short example:

```dart
library view;

abstract class View {
  factory View({HtmlElement host}) = ViewImpl;

  void enable() {}
}

class ViewImpl implements View {
  HtmlElement host;

  ViewImpl({this.host});

  @override
  void enable() {
    host.classes.remove('disabled');
  }
}
```

In another library:

```dart
library button; // notice, this is another library

abstract class Button extends View {
  factory Button({String title, HtmlElement host}) = ButtonImpl; // The magic happens here!
}

class ButtonImpl extends ViewImpl implements Button {
  String title; // voila, a protected property

  ButtonImpl({this.title, HtmlElement host}) : super(host: host);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```dart
final button = new Button(title: "Cancel", host: element);

button.title // => cannot access!
```

Moreover, you can access the protected field in e.g. a unit test:

```dart
// Instantiate the *Impl class to side-step the protection.
final button = new ButtonImpl(title: "Cancel", host: element);
expect(button.title, equals("Cancel"); // => it works!
```

In short, you hide your 'protected' methods in Impl classes. You can freely extend the implementation in different libraries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/horadeaventura/images/3/3a/Brain_explode.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130202043723&path-prefix=es

Comment: I am not able to understand the above solution. Especially the code in button library. What magic is happening in the Button factory constructor? Anybody care to explain a bit?

Comment: Where did the `enable` method being overridden come from? This is hard to follow

Comment: Difficult for me to understand this code and even if I would understand it, it seems so complicated and adds so much code that it simply isn't worth it just for getting a protected member. For me, which will work in 90% of the cases, I simply wrap the classes in a library in order for the private members to be accessible as protected for all the classes in that library.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar by taking advantage of the library as the boundary of privacy, like so:

```dart
library greetings;

abstract class Greeting {
   void _sendGreeting(String greeting) => print(greeting);
}

class HugGreeting extends Greeting {
  void sendHug() => _sendGreeting("Hug");
}
```

And in your main file:

```dart
import 'greetings.dart';

HugGreeting hug = new HugGreeting();
hug.sendHug();
```

That way, only classes that extend from `Greeting` *and* reside in the same library can access the low-level `_sendGreeting()` method.

Comment: Sometime you cannot have the same lib, or you don't want to.
I also miss (java) protected keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This limits the callers to subclasses and everything which has access to private members of these subclasses.

** library greeting

```dart
class GreetingEvent {
  final message;
  GreetingEvent(this.message);
  toString() => message;
}

abstract class Greeting {
  // The sub class has to pass a method to the super constructor
  // which allows to set a private field in the sub class.
  Greeting(Function setProtected) {
    // passes "this" so the passed static method has an instance
    // context
    setProtected(this, new GreetingProtected(this));
  }

  // protected
  void _sendGreeting(GreetingEvent event) {
    print(event);
  }
}

// This class provides access to protected members of Greeting
// by just forwarding calls
class GreetingProtected {
  // protected
  final _greeting;
  GreetingProtected(this._greeting);

  void sendGreeting(GreetingEvent event) => _greeting._sendGreeting(event);
}
```

** library custom_greeting

```dart
library custom_greeting;

import 'greeting.dart';

class HugGreeting extends Greeting {
  // the reference to the 
  GreetingProtected _protected;
  // pass the method to the super constructor which can 
  // assign the protected-forwarder
  HugGreeting() : super(_setProtected);

  // Method passed to the super constructor to pass
  // the protected-forwarder
  // Has to be static so it can be passed in the constructors
  // super call.
  static _setProtected(HugGreeting greeting, GreetingProtected protected) =>
      greeting._protected = protected;

  void someMethod() {
    // code here uses sendGreeting()
    _protected.sendGreeting(new GreetingEvent('someMethod'));
  }
}
```

** main

```dart
library main;
import 'custom_greeting.dart';
import 'greeting.dart';

void main() {
  var hug = new HugGreeting();
  //hug.sendGreeting(new GreetingEvent('someMessage'));
  // should not compile => and doesn't
  hug.someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Why don't you use the almost standard prefix _ to mark function as private or protected?

I don't think you should completely block access to a private or protected function. Sure, let the user know that's access isn't wanted, but you shouldn't block it. Just today, I found a bug in dart-sdk. I could have override the faulty function and still use the rest of the class, but the class was marked as private... I needed to copy the class back inside my application... but I have been lucky here because it was not depending on anything else, but I remember doing something similar in c# for listview which I ended up recreating the complete library with hundred of private class just to make a small change.

```dart
library greeting;

abstract class Greeting {
   void _sendGreeting(GreetingEvent event) { ... }
}
```

```dart
library custom_greeting;
import 'greeting.dart';

class HugGreeting extends Greeting {
   // code here uses _sendGreeting()
}
```

```dart
library main;
import 'custom_greeting.dart';

var hug = new HugGreeting();
hug._sendGreeting(...); // should compile, maybe with a warning...
```

Comment: This ` // code here uses _sendGreeting()` fails because the method `_sendGreeting` in the base class is private and the base class is in another library.