# In Dart, how to access a parent private var from a subclass in another file?

Tags: dart, subclass, private, privileges

I have two classes in Dart, MyClass1 and MyClass2 where MyClass2 extends MyClass1. In some of MyClass2 functions, I want to access a variable that has "private" access privileges in MyClass1.
If MyClass1 and MyClass2 are declared in the same dart file, like this:

```
class MyClass1 {
  double _myprivatevar;
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

  MyClass2(double myvar){
    this._myprivatevar = myvar;
  }
}
```

everything is fine
But now, if MyClass2 is declared in its own dart file:

```
import 'package:test/myclass1.dart';

class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

  MyClass2 (double myvar){
    this._myprivatevar = myvar;
  }
}
```

I have an error saying:

> The setter '_myprivatevar' isn't defined for the class 'MyClass2'. Try
>   importing the library that defines '_myprivatevar', correcting the
>   name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field
>   named '_myprivatevar'.dart(undefined_setter)

how can I solve this issue and have access to a parent private variable from a subclass defined in another dart file?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot directly access a private name from a different library, and Dart does not have any privacy notation corresponding to "protected" (access from subclasses).

You have to either make the property public, declare the two classes in the same library, or not access the property from the subclass. There are no other options.

If your only issue is *initializing* an instance variable, then you could perhaps pass the value of the variable as a constructor argument to the superclass, thereby having the superclass access the variable for you:

```
class MyClass1 {
  double _myPrivateVar;
  MyClass1([double myPrivateValue]) : _myPrivateVar = myPrivateValue;
}
// In different library:
class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {
  MyClass2(double myVar) : super(myVar);
}
```

That won't help you *read* the private variable later, it's still only the superclass, and other code in the same library, which can access the variable.

Comment: Unfortunately my issue is not just accessing the private var from the constructor (it was just for the example). I need to access the private var from the subclass in multiple functions. I guess I would declare MyClass1 and MyClass2 as part of the same library as a workaround until Dart decide to have the concept of "protected" vars implemented (hopefully they would realize this is really a usefull missing feature...)

Comment: What I don't really understand though is that my two .dart files containing MyClass1 and MyClass2 are part of the same Flutter project and in the same folder. Isn't a Flutter project supposed to be consider as a single library? (in which case my classes are already part of the same lib so I don't understand why I have this error)

Comment: Flutter projects are Dart *packages* (or more precisely: Pub packages). They can contain multiple Dart libraries. Each Dart file is either a library file or a part file, which can be included in libraries. Anything you `import` is a library by itself.

Comment: @Irn OK thanks for the explanation. Is there a simple way to define two dart files as beeing parts of the same library inside a Flutter project (without having to define an external library with its own pubspec file and lib directory)?

Comment: Dart part files are for that. You create one library file normally, call it `lib_file.dart`, and on part file, call it `part_file.dart`, then you add `part "part_file.dart";` to the library file and `part of "lib_file.dart";` at the top of the `part_file.dart` file, and then, effectively, the part file is included in the library. (I'd like to point you to a good resource for `part` files, but they are generally discouraged in favor of individual libraries, when possible, or just putting all the classes in one file instead of separate parts. You can do that too.)

Answer (score 6):

You can use @protected annotation for this.

```
class MyClass1 {
  double _myprivatevar;

  @protected double get myprivatevar => _myprivatevar;

  @protected set myprivatevar(newValue) {
    _myprivatevar = newValue;
  }
    
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

  MyClass2(double myvar){
    myprivatevar = myvar;
  }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350655/how-do-i-emulate-protected-methods-in-dart) and [Github issue link](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3193#issuecomment-189379596)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `part/ part of`

```
// lib.dart
library lib
part 'class1.dart'
part 'class2.dart'

// class1.dart
part of lib

// class2.dart
part of lib
```