# Extension of abstract class doesn't work properly in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I have faced with strange behavior of extensions of abstract class in the Dart.

#### The Code

I have following files:

**BaseListItem.dart**

```
abstract class BaseListItem {
  ImageProvider get _icon;
  IHealthChecker get _healthChecker;
  String get _name;
  String get _unit;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     ... build widgets tree ... 
  }
}
```

**Temperature.dart**

```
class Temperature extends BaseListItem {
   @override
  IHealthChecker get _healthChecker => TemperatureHealthChecker();

  @override
  ImageProvider<Object> get _icon => const Svg('assets/images/icons/Temperature.svg');

  @override
  String get _name => "Temperature";

  @override
  String get _unit => "°C";
}
```

And all this inheritance stuff I am using in **SensorsList.dart** file.

```
class SensorsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _StateSensorsList();
}

class _StateSensorsList extends State<SensorsList> {
  final List<BaseListItem> sensors = [Temperature(), Humidity()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: sensors.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return sensors[index].build(context);
        });
  }
}
```

#### The problem

This code built but fail at run time with next exception

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Temperature' has no instance getter '_icon'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Temperature'
Tried calling: _icon)
```

❗️The problem disappears if I put abstract class BaseListItem and his extension Temperature into a single file.❗️

Comment: nitpick on terminology: an extension is something else. a class that extends another class is called a subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it happens is because the variables are private. Private variables can only be accessed within the same file. See also [In Dart, how to access a parent private var from a subclass in another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58715755/in-dart-how-to-access-a-parent-private-var-from-a-subclass-in-another-file)