# how to make a property is only readable from abstract class in Dart?

Tags: dart

```
abstract class ListController {

   int numberOfDocumentPerPage = 7;

}
```

then use the abstract class

```
class EventListController extends ListController {


}
```

but when I make an instance, I can change/assign the new value to the property

```
final controller = EventListController();
controller.numberOfDocumentPerPage = 1000; // should be error in here
```

so how to make a property is only readable from abstract class ?

UPDATE:

I also need to modify the property inside EventListController class

Comment: You are looking for "protected" - there was a lengthy discussion about that; https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926556/7362396

Comment: @TobiasK. protected is not necessary just to make a property read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want the base class to declare a public getter.  I think the simplest way would be:

```dart
abstract class ListController {
  static const defaultNumberOfDocumentPerPage = 7;

  int get numberOfDocumentPerPage => defaultNumberOfDocumentPerPage;
}

class EventListController extends ListController {
  int _numberOfDocumentPerPage = ListController.defaultNumberOfDocumentPerPage;

  @override
  int get numberOfDocumentPerPage => _numberOfDocumentPerPage;
}
```

If you don't want the separate named constant, you could explicitly initialize your internal value with the result of calling the original getter:

```dart
abstract class ListController {
  final int numberOfDocumentPerPage = 7;
}

class EventListController extends ListController {
  EventListController() {
    _numberOfDocumentPerPage = super.numberOfDocumentPerPage;
  }
  
  // ignore: super_in_invalid_context, https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46850
  late int _numberOfDocumentPerPage = super.numberOfDocumentPerPage;

  @override
  int get numberOfDocumentPerPage => _numberOfDocumentPerPage;
}
```

Another approach would be to provide a protected setter in the base class:

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

abstract class ListController {
  int _numberOfDocumentPerPage = 7;

  int get numberOfDocumentPerPage => _numberOfDocumentPerPage;

  @protected
  set numberOfDocumentPerPage(int value) => _numberOfDocumentPerPage = value;
}
```

But note that the [`@protected` annotation](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/protected-constant.html) just provides a hint to the analyzer so that it can warn about violations; it is not enforced at compilation-time nor at runtime.